# PHP Warning: file_get_contents

Tags: php, warnings, file-get-contents

So 2 days ago I got this message:

> PHP Warning: file_get_contents(http://example.com): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/server/map/index.php on line 30

This is what I've on line 29 and 30:

```
$url = 'http://example.com';

$string = file_get_contents($url);
```

The fun part is that I can see the external content on my local host. But not when I upload it to the server. Then I can only see the html + css included in the index.php file.

What I'm trying to do is to get all the available objects from the external website and post them on my website.

I've done it with a several other pages. But now encountered problems with some of them.

Anyone here who has any exemepl on how I can solve it with php.
Possibly a completely different solution?

Comment: sounds like maybe your server can't access that web page?

Comment: @ADyson 
Do you have any idea how I can solve it? server settings or similar?

Comment: well you need to check if the server is allowed to make external network calls. Perhaps there's a firewall or routing config preventing it. Maybe log onto to it if you can, and find out if it can ping that host from the command line, or ping any other common site (e.g. google or something). But really, to solve it, that would be a sysadmin question better suited to the ServerFault site.

Comment: BTW: it works for me online, I saw a lot of pictures :) I'm not really sure I properly understood what [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) says (as english is not my native language) but could it be also because script is trying to read all directory and then get timed out ? or is it just, as ADyson says, a problem to access the server ? (file_gets_content was not denied as I was able to use your code)

Comment: @OldPadawan To be more specific: This is my site http://fbapp.visionmedia.nu/. And my Trying to only get the "Houses" with my php script. From http://angelaget.se/till-salu/). This is what it looks like on localhost: https://i.gyazo.com/ff9d9630063755a96201bc6d8cf07d7a.png

Comment: file_get_contents will only read whatever is at the URL you give, whether that's a HTML document, some JSON, a binary file, or whatever. But it will be a single resource. It won't read a whole directory on the remote server. It's more likely to be timing out because it can't reach the remote host, or the connection is too slow and the resource it's downloading is too big to download over a slow connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `file_get_contents` function remotely, but many hosts don't allow this. If you must use `file_get_contents` method, try to change `default_socket_timeout` option in PHP configuration in file `php.ini`
 or before your code insert:

`ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 900); // 900 Seconds = 15 Minutes`

This should help with connection timed out. But I would recommend using some PHP frameworks or just CURL:
[Client URL Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

For example:

```
function get_data($url) {   
    $ch = curl_init();  
    $timeout = 900; // 900 Seconds = 15 Minutes 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);     
    $data = curl_exec($ch);     
    curl_close($ch);    
    return $data; 
}
```

The Usage:

`$returned_content = get_data('http://www.angelaget.se/till-salu/');`

Comment: I'll try and see what happens :) As I commented abow this is what I'm trying to do haha... This is my site fbapp.visionmedia.nu. And my Trying to only get the "Houses" with my php script. From angelaget.se/till-salu). This is what it looks like on localhost: https://i.gyazo.com/ff9d9630063755a96201bc6d8cf07d7a.png

Comment: @Jakob First, you have to get all site content (from angelaget.se/till-salu) to string. Try this using the code above. Next, I must use  tools like  [Dom Module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to properly cut html code and leave the "Houses" alone.